# How to change the value of a Key within an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, key, symbols

I want to change the value of `:sym3` to `"A"` after using the `if` code I provided . However I don't want to access it by explicitly changing the value of `:sym3` so if I do iterate over other arrays containing other symbols I can do so if one does not match the other two.
What's the best possible way to go about doing so?

Once my if statement runs and I see that one of the keys is equal to "B" I want to change that key's value to "A"

```
hash = {:sym1 => "A", :sym2 => "A", :sym3 => "B"}
array = [:sym1, :sym2, :sym3]
if hash.values_at(*array).count("A") == 2 and @spaces.values_at(*array).count("B") == 1

else

end
```

Comment: A symbol cannot have a value `"A"`. A hash can have a value `"A"` for a key.

Comment: I do not really understand the question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Once my if statement runs and I see that one of the keys is equal to "B" I want to change that key's value to "A" @hirolau

Comment: I would just do this: hash[hash.key('B')] = 'A', but I feel I am missing something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the answer you are looking for (just iterating through it)?

```
hash = {:sym1 => "A", :sym2 => "A", :sym3 => "B"}
array = [:sym1, :sym2, :sym3]

hash.each do |key, value|
  if value == "B"
    hash[key] = "A"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of :sym3, then use this code:

```
hash[array[2]]="A"
```

Comment: "2"!? Why are we encouraging using magic numbers in index?

Answer (score -1):

You don't say whether your hashes always have three elements, or what to do if, say, all the elements have different values. But I wonder if this is what you want?

It groups the contents of the hash by value, picks the majority group and sets all values of the hash to the most common value.

```
hash = {:sym1 => "A", :sym2 => "A", :sym3 => "B"}

majority = hash.group_by { |pair| pair[1] }.max_by { |group| group[1].size }
hash.each_key { |key| hash[key] = majority[0] }

p hash
```

**output**

```
{:sym1=>"A", :sym2=>"A", :sym3=>"A"}
```

Comment: My original hash has more than 3 elements, however my array will always only have 3. Thank you for your help however this is more code than I need for my particular issue